# SQL Matrix - Attach Rate

Tags: sql, sql-server, matrix

I'm trying to find the attach rate of certain categories in retail and want to create a matrix table because I'm working with about 65 categories.  In order to find the attach rate, we need attach items/sale items:

So if I'm working with categories - jeans and t-shirts, if they bought 25 t-shirts in Q1, and 75 jeans in Q1, t-shirts would have an attach rate of 33%.

If I have a table consisting of ordernumber, category, qtysold, how would I be able to achieve an attach rate?

```
|OrderNumber|Category|PurchaseQty|
----------------------------
|   1       |Jeans   |  1      |
|   2       |Jeans   |   3     |
|   2       |TShirt  |   1     |
---------------------------
```

For the example above, the Overall Attach Rate for T-Shirts would be 25% (1 Tshirt/4 Pairs of Jeans).

I hope this makes sense - happy to clarify anything that doesn't make sense.

Thank you!

Comment: I *sort of* get your calculation, but not entirely. What do you want your result to look like? Just a single scalar value? seems like you can achieve the calculation you laid out by just summing up the number of Jeans and TShirts and dividing them. You could do this with variables, or subqueries

Comment: @Ally  Thanks for posting the second question.   Is this by customer (like in your first) or is this in aggregate.  What is the desired output

Comment: ...should the attach rate be per the _total_ items (eg, rate for shirts should be 1 shirt / (1 shirt + 4 jeans) = 20%), total for all items not this one, or just the highest item; it may be helpful to add another item to your source sample, and what about example results?

Comment: @John - It is not by customer, it is an aggregate for the quarter.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse - so it's not a total item, the attach rate would define how often someone bought t-shirts when they bought jeans, so that's why it's just the 1 shirt/4 jeans = 25%. 

so if we added shoes and order 1 bought 2 pairs of shoes, the attach rate of shoes to jeans would be 50%.  

hope this helps.

Comment: @Xedni - since i'm working wth 65 categories, i'd ideally like a matrix that has a category on the y axis and the same categories on the x axis with a attach rate in the matrix cells.

Answer (score 0):

So if I've understood your question correctly, you just want the ratio of every category to every other category, is that right? SQL doesn't lend itself nicely to constructing your results as a 65x65 matrix, but you can quite easily represent it with a columns representing the category and value of the numerator and denominator (note, if you *really* need it as a 65x65 grid, you'll have to look up dynamic pivoting. I really wouldn't recommend it unless you need it that way for some reason).

Just sum up each category, then cross join that aggregation with itself (excluding same-category joins), and do your division.

```
declare @src table
(
    OrderNum int,
    Category varchar(10),
    Qty int
)

insert into @src
select 1, 'Jeans', 1 union all
select 2, 'Jeans', 3 union all
select 2, 'TShirt', 1 union all
select 1, 'Shoes', 2

;with agg as
(
    select 
        Category, 
        Qty = sum(qty)
    from @src
    group by Category
)
select 
    Category = a.Category,
    CategoryCount = a.Qty,
    ComparisonCategory = b.Category,
    ComparisonCategoryCount = b.Qty,
    Ratio = (a.Qty * 1.0) / nullif(b.Qty, 0)
from agg a
inner join agg b
    on a.Category != b.Category
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
SELECT T.orderid, T.Category, T.Qty, (T.Qty / T.SumQty)*100 AS Persentage
FROM (
SELECT 
orderid, 
category, 
Qty,
CAST(SUM(Qty) OVER(PARTITION BY Category) AS DECIMAL) AS SumQty
FROM dbo.ORDERs
) T
```